# Force core dump on RHEL 6

Tags: c++, coredump, rhel6

How do I force a process to core dump on RHEL 6?

I tried `kill -3 <pid>`, but the process is still running.

`kill -SIGSEGV <pid>` kills the process, but no core is generated :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'omni_thread_fatal'
EVServices: ./../../../rw/db/dbref.h:251: T *RWDBCountedRef<T>::operator->() const [with T = RWDBHandleImp]: Assertion `(impl_) != 0' failed.
/evaluate/ev_dev87/shl/StartProcess.sh[69]: wait: 35225: Killed
Thu Dec  5 11:14:03 EST 2013  Exited EVServices, pid=35225, with ERROR returncode=265 signal=SIGKILL
```

Please tell me what else I can try to force a process to create a core dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SIGABRT to generate a core dump: `kill -6 <pid>`

This requires the running process to be allowed to write core dumps, issue `ulimit -c unlimited` in the same shell as the one used to run your program, before running that program.

Comment: ulimit -c is set to unlimited.

Comment: ulimit -c is set to unlimited.
On using that signal, I get this:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'omni_thread_fatal'
EVServices: ./../../../rw/db/dbref.h:251: T *RWDBCountedRef<T>::operator->() const [with T = RWDBHandleImp]: Assertion `(impl_) != 0' failed.
/evaluate/ev_dev88/shl/StartProcess.sh[69]: wait: 1190: Killed
Thu Dec  5 12:54:03 EST 2013  Exited EVServices, pid=1190, with ERROR returncode=265 signal=SIGKILL
I don't see any core in that folder, or the folder I have set up to get cores (/tmp/cores). Other cores get generated in that folder

Comment: @roymustang86 In that case something in your code or some library you use is catching the signals that would cause a coredump.(or there's permission problems on  /tmp/cores/). There's traces of a shell script in there, if you're starting a shell script, make sure it doesn't set up another environment/runs as another user/etc. with coredumps disabled. Otherwise you'll have to find and remove the code that stops core dump signals, or possibly connect to the process with gdb and generate a coredump from within the debugger.

Comment: You were right, the Oracle client library was catching the signals, and on disabling the SIG_ERR_HANDLER in the oracle library, core dumps are generated successfully.